# Array filtering

Tags: javascript, node.js

I wrote a program that's supposed to output all the names of files having a defined extension in a defined folder, however when I add the following line:

```
list = list.filter(file => { file !== fileExtension });
```

Which I want to filter the files which name matches an extension name (A file called "txt" for example), I get not output.

Here is the complete code (I use node JavaScript to run it):

```js
const fs = require('fs');

const dirPath = process.argv[2];
const fileExtension = process.argv[3];

fs.readdir(dirPath, (err, list) => {
    if (err) {
        return console.log('An error occurred while reading directory: ' + err);
    }  

    list = list.filter(file => { file !== fileExtension }); // No output when I add this line

    list = list.filter(file => file.split('.')[file.split('.').length - 1] === fileExtension);

    list.forEach((file) => {  
        console.log(file);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to return the boolean:

```
list = list.filter(file => { return file !== fileExtension });
```

or

```
list = list.filter(file => file !== fileExtension);
```